# what is the Mathematica command for the Euler numbers $E_k?$

Tags: special-functions, summation, coding-style, command-line

We know that the [Euler numbers $(E_r)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers) has many integral and series representations but I am wondering if there is a simpler Mathematica command.

Comment: If I enter "euler numbers" in the search bar of the documentation center, `EulerE` is the first hit....

Comment: @Michael E2 thank you so much

Comment: the question is closed due to " off topic" ?!!!!!!! no comment.

Comment: The question is marked, "it is **easily found in the documentation.**" Don't you agree that if one searches for "euler numbers", it is easy to find? (I was happy to help by showing you how you can find such answers within Mathematica. I think of it as teaching someone to fish. You also got an answer that just gave you the fish, but they like answering whatever gets asked and are a sweetheart in a different way. The community often gives answers to folks' questions even when the questions meet a closure criterion.)

Comment: @Michael E2 I agree its easy to find but could be useful for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EulerE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerE.html):

[image]

```
 Table[EulerE[k], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, -1, 0, 5, 0, -61, 0, 1385, 0, -50521}
> ```

Comment: Thank you soooo much.